# Ускорение базы WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, memcached

Возникла острая проблема(( Новостной сайт на базе WordPress. После установки темы, плагинов и записи около 5 тысяч постов в базу всё было хорошо. Подключено много скриптов, стилей, картинки не оптимизированы. В будущем это будет исправлено. !НО! сайт летал. Дополнительно установил Sphinx. Поиск стал работать раза в 2-3 быстрее.

После переноса в базу WordPress около 192 тысяч новостей, посты стали грузиться около 5-6 секунд. В админке медиафайлы стали грузиться вообще очень долго. В чём проблема? Как мне ускорить сайт? Есть же другие крупные сайты на базе WordPress... У них базы куда больше, чем у меня. И работают они прекрасно.

Comment: Начните сначала с замеров таймеров: как долго запросы в базе отрабатывают, как долго генерятся страницы, как долго грузится до пользователя. Без этой информации будет гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: И какой помощи вы ожидаете? У других сайтов и код другой, а мы телепатическим взглядом должны сказать, где у вас в коде проблема не видя его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с анализа с помощью плагина [Query Monitor](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). Какие запросы в базу слишком тяжёлые? Сколько их? Можно ли их оптимизировать?

Проблема может быть в неоптимальных настройках сервера. Почитайте мою статью 
[10,000 соединений в секунду на WordPress — возможно!](https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/). Там приведены общие рекомендации по настройкам MySQL, php, nginx.

Возможно, придётся оптимизировать код. В этом случае без профилирования никак. Посмотрите видео Геннадия Ковшенина на эту тему:

- [Профилирование кода в WordPress](https://wordpress.tv/2014/08/25/gennady-kovshenin-profiling-wordpress/)
- [Профилирование сайта на WordPress №1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRMGPm0EVmI)

Comment: @LexXy  Небольшой, но это не имеет никакого значения. Там всё закешировано, дело даже до php не доходит, какая база?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin показывает 1.1 Gb. Движок был MariaDB. Сейчас MySQL.

Comment: @LexXy можно, в профиле есть сайт, а на нём - Скайп